# Why my Out-File does not write output into the file

Tags: powershell

```
$ready = Read-Host "How many you want?: "
$i = 0
do{
    (-join(1..12 | ForEach {((65..90)+(97..122)+(".") | % {[char]$_})+(0..9)+(".") | Get-Random}))
    $i++
} until ($i -match $ready) Out-File C:/numbers.csv -Append
```

If I give a value of 10 to the script - it will generate 10 random numbers and shows it on pshell. It even generates new file called numbers.csv. However, it does not add the generated output to the file. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your `Out-File C:/numbers.csv -Append` call is a completely *separate statement* from your `do` loop**, and an `Out-File` call without any input simply creates an *empty* file.<sup>[1]</sup>

**You need to chain (connect) commands with `|`** in order to make them run in a [*pipeline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines).

However, **with a *statement* such as as a `do { ... } until` loop, this won't work as-is**, but you can **convert such a statement to a *command*** that you can use as part of a pipeline by enclosing it in a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) and invoking it with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (to run in a *child* [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes)), or `.`, the [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) (to run directly in the caller's scope):

```
[int] $ready = Read-Host "How many you want?"
$i = 0
& { 
  do{
    -join (1..12 | foreach { 
      (65..90 + 97..122 + '.' | % { [char] $_ }) +(0..9) + '.' | Get-Random
    })
    $i++
  } until ($i -eq $ready)
} | Out-File C:/numbers.csv -Append
```

<sup>Note the `[int]` type constraint to convert the [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) output, which is always a *string*, to a number, and the use of the [`-eq` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) rather than the text- and regex-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) in the `until` condition; also, unnecessary grouping with `(...)` has been removed.</sup>

Note: An **alternative** to the use of a script block with either the `&` or `.` operator is to use **`$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)**, as shown in [MikeM's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529232/45375).  The difference between the two approaches is that the former *streams* its output to the pipeline - i.e., outputs objects *one by one* - whereas `$(...)` invariably collects all output *in memory, up front*.

For smallish input sets this won't make much of a difference, but the in-memory collection that `$(...)` performs can become problematic with large input sets, so **the `& { ... }` / `. { ... }` approach is generally preferable**.

---

[Arno van Boven' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529057/45375) shows **a simpler alternative to your `do ... until` loop** based on a **`for` loop**.

Combining a [**`foreach` loop**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) with `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), is even more concise and expressive (and the cost of the array construction is usually negligible and overall still amounts to noticeably faster execution):

```
[int] $ready = Read-Host "How many you want?"
& { 
  foreach ($i in 1..$ready) {
    -join (1..12 | foreach { 
      ([char[]] (65..90 + 97..122)) + 0..9 + '.' | Get-Random 
    })
  }
} | Out-File C:/numbers.csv -Append
```

<sup>The above also shows a simplification of the original command via a `[char[]]` cast that directly converts an array of code points to an array of characters.</sup>

In **PowerShell [Core] 7+**, you could further simplify by taking advantage of [`Get-Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random)'s `-Count` parameter:

```
[int] $ready = Read-Host "How many you want?"
& { 
  foreach ($i in 1..$ready) {
    -join (
      ([char[]] (65..90 + 97..122)) + 0..9 + '.' | Get-Random -Count 12
    )
  }
} | Out-File C:/numbers.csv -Append
```

---

And, finally, **you could have avoided a *statement* for looping altogether, and used the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* instead** (whose built-in alias, perhaps confusingly, is *also* `foreach`, but there'a also `%`), as you're already doing *inside* your loop (`1..12 | foreach ...`):

```
[int] $ready = Read-Host "How many you want?"
1..$ready | ForEach-Object {
  -join (1..12 | ForEach-Object { 
    ([char[]] (65..90 + 97..122)) + 0..9 + '.' | Get-Random 
  })
} | Out-File C:/numbers.csv -Append
```

---

<sup>[1] In *Windows PowerShell*, `Out-File` uses UTF-16LE ("Unicode") encoding by default, so even a *conceptually* empty file still contains 2 bytes, namely the UTF-16LE *BOM*. In *PowerShell [Core] v6+*, BOM-less UTF-8 is the default across all cmdlets, so there you'll truly get an empty (`0` bytes) file.</sup>

Comment: Not sure I like `foreach ($i in 1..$ready)`, because there are too many concepts going on there. That is of course a personal preference, but IMHO this crosses the border from magic to black magic :)

Comment: Time to embrace the magic, @ArnovanBoven: this is both PowerShell-idiomatic and performs better than a quotidian `for` loop, which is really a bit player in the PowerShell world.

Comment: Not a PS expert; I like `for` loops because they are closer to my 'natural habitat'. I'm actually surprised that your construct performs better! (I'll take your word for it).

Comment: @ArnovanBoven, yes, it's not obvious, but the explanation lies in the distinction between what PowerShell _itself_ does - such as a `..` operation - and what is done in _user code_: the former is much faster than the latter.

Comment: The performance difference is amazing! Consider me converted :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to wrap the loop in a sub-expression and pipe it:

```
$ready = Read-Host "How many you want?: "
$i = 0
$(do{
    (-join(1..12 | ForEach {((65..90)+(97..122)+(".") | % {[char]$_})+(0..9)+(".") | Get-Random}))
    $i++
} until ($i -match $ready)) | Out-File C:/numbers.csv -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally avoid `Do` loops when I can, because I find them hard to read. Combining the two previous answers, I'd write it like this, because I find it easier to tell what is going on. Using a `for` loop instead, every line becomes its own self-contained piece of logic.

```
[int]$amount = Read-Host "How many you want?: "
& {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $amount; $i++) {
        -join(1..12 | foreach {((65..90)+(97..122)+(".") | foreach {[char]$_})+(0..9)+(".") | Get-Random})
    }   
 } | Out-File C:\numbers.csv -Append
```

(Please do not accept this as an answer, this is just showing another way of doing it)